How to evaluate $I=\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\arccos(x)\,dx$
$$I=\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\arccos(x)\,dx$$
$$\arccos(x)=t \implies -\sin(t)\,dt=dx$$
$$I=\int_0^{1} \ln\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\arccos(x)\,dx\implies \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{1+\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{1+\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{1-\sin(t)}{1+\sin(t)}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt$$
I couldn't find any nice identities that would simplify the part in the log, however I did try
$$\frac{1-\sin(t)}{1+\sin(t)}=\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\right)^2$$
But this seems to make the integral really hard, I am interested in learning better initial set up for evaluating this integral

Wolfarmalpha gives $2 \ln 2 - 2$. Maybe try using $\ln {\frac{a]{b}} = \ln a - \ln b$ and solving the resulting integrals

@Kraken are you sure? its this

I evaluated the integrals after applying the ln identity, seems like i messed subtracting them :sweat_smile:

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \ln\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arccos x\,dx\\
=& \int_0^1 \arccos x\,d\bigg(x \ln\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}-2 \arcsin x \bigg)\\
\overset{ibp}=& \int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2} }
 \bigg(x \ln\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}-2 \arcsin x \bigg)dx\\
=&\bigg(2\ln x -\sqrt{1-x^2}\ln\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}- \arcsin^2x \bigg)_0^1 \\
=&\  -2\ln2 -\frac{\pi^2}4
\end{align}

Damn! Wouldn't be able to think of such a differential, Thank you sir

$$\begin{align*}
I&=\int^1_0 \ln\left({\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}}\right)\arccos(x)dx\overset{IBP}{=}-2\int^1_0\frac{x\arccos(x)-\sqrt{1-x^2}+1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx \\&= 2\int^1_0\frac{-\arccos(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx-2\int^1_0\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\&=-\frac{\pi^2}{4}-2\ln(2) \end{align*}$$

Here's the thing I was discussing regarding how hard it gets on using this identity;
$$\frac{1-\sin(t)}{1+\sin(t)}=\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\right)^2$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}{1+\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{1-\sin(t)}{1+\sin(t)}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{1-\sin(t)}{1+\sin(t)}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt$$
$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{1-\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{1+\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt$$
$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\frac{1-\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{1+\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\right)t\sin(t)\,dt=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)t\sin(t)\,dt$$
$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)t\sin(t)\,dt=8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(t))\cos(2t)\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-t\right)\,dt$$
$$8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(t))\cos(2t)\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-t\right)\,dt=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(t))\cos(2t)\left({2\pi}\right)\,dt-8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}t\ln(\tan(t))\cos(2t)\,dt$$
Now evaluating the first integral,
$$2\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(t))\cos(2t)\,dt=2\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(t))\,d\left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}\right)$$
Integrating by parts,
We get,
$$2\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(t))\,d\left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{2}\tag1$$
Now evaluating the second integral,
$$8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}t\ln(\tan(t))\cos(2t)\,dt=8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}t\ln(\tan(t))\,d\left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}\right)$$
Integrating by parts,
We get,
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}t\ln(\tan(t))\,d\left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}\right)=\frac{-1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(2t)\left(\ln(\tan(t))+t(\sec^2t\cot t\right))\,dt$$
$$-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}t+\sin(t)\cos(t)\ln(\tan(t)\,dt=-\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(2t)\ln(\tan(t))\,dt$$
$$-\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(2t)\ln(\tan(t))\,dt=-\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(t))\,d\left(\frac{1-\cos(t)}{2}\right)$$
Integrating by parts,
We get,
$$-8\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\tan(t))\,d\left(\frac{1-\cos(t)}{2}\right)\right)=-2\ln(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\tag2$$
Our result then ends up being $(1)+(2)$,
$$I=-\frac{\pi^2}{4}-2\ln(2)$$

Let’s start with OP’s last integral.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(\frac{1-\sin t}{1+\sin t}\right) t \sin t d t \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(\frac{1-\cos t}{1+\cos t}\right)(\frac\pi 2-t) \cos t d t \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(\frac{2 \sin ^2 \frac{t}{2}}{2 \cos ^2 \frac{t}{2}}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right) \cos t d t \\
& =2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(\tan \frac{t}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right) \cos t d t \\
& =2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(\tan \frac{t}{2}\right) d\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \sin t-t \sin t-\cos t+1\right) \\
&\overset{IBP}{=}-2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \sin t-t \sin t-\cos t+1\right) \frac{1}{\sin t} d t \\
&=  -2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t-\frac{\cos t}{\sin t}+\frac{1}{\sin t}\right) d t \\
& =-2\left(\frac{\pi^2}{8}+\ln 2\right) \\
& =-\frac{\pi^2}{4}-2 \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.
